# Calling C++ function which accepts and returns std::string from Python

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I'm trying to call C++ function using ctypes. The function declaration looks like

```
std::string some_function( const std::string &param )
```

As Python can not interact with C++ directly, I have created a C-wrapper for this function as follows

```
const char *my_function( const char *param )
{
  std::string result = some_function( std::string( param ) );
  char *ret = new char[result.length() + 1];
  strcpy(ret, result.c_str());
  return ret;
}
```

And Python wrapper

```
def my_function(param):
    func = lib.my_function
    func.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p]
    func.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
    result = func(ctypes.c_char_p(param))
    return result
```

But when I try to call Python wrapper with some bytes passed as param, for example

```
my_function(b'GP\x00\x01\xe6\x10\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x1ex\xcb\xa16l\xf1\xbfp\xe6\xaa\xc89\x81\xdd?')
```

It fails with the following error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_create
```

I'm not very good in C and C++. Can you help me to figure out how to create correct wrapper? Thanks.

Comment: the parameter you pass has no terminating `\0` (unless python adds it, not sure about that)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Nah, it does: in fact, there’s a null terminator at index 2. (Of course this surely isn’t what OP wants.)

Comment: You should be able to print out the contents of the parameter in `my_function` before trying to create a string from it to see what it looks like. Either in a debugger or just `std::cout`/`printf`. I'm not really familiar with ctypes but nothing you're doing really stands out to me as being wrong.

Comment: "call C++ function using ctypes" Well ctypes is not called c++types, and for a reason. Perhaps you want to use something more suitable for C++, such as pybind11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your data contains embedded nulls, `c_char_p` won't work as it assumes the returned `char*` is null-terminated and converts the data up to the first null found to a `bytes` object.  `std::string` as used also makes that assumption when pass a `char*` only, so it needs the data length as well.

To manage a data buffer with null content, the size of the input data must be passed in and the size of the output data must be returned.  You'll also have to manage freeing the data allocated in the C++ code.

The below code demonstrates everything:

test.cpp - compiled with `cl /EHsc /W4 /LD test.cpp` with Microsoft Visual Studio.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

// Windows DLLs need functions to be explicitly exported
#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

std::string some_function(const std::string& param) {
    return param + std::string("some\x00thing", 10);
}

// pLength is used as an input/output parameter.
// Pass in input length and get output length back.
extern "C" API
const char* my_function(const char* param, size_t* pLength) {
    auto result = some_function(std::string(param, *pLength));
    auto reslen = result.length();
    auto res = new char[reslen];
    // Use memcpy to handle embedded nulls
    memcpy_s(res, reslen, result.data(), reslen);
    *pLength = reslen;
    return res;
}

extern "C" API
void my_free(const char* param) {
    delete [] param;
}
```

test.py

```py
import ctypes as ct

dll = ct.CDLL('./test')

# Note: A restype of ct.c_char_p is converted to a bytes object
#       and access to the returned C pointer is lost.  Use
#       POINTER(c_char) instead to retain access and allow it
#       to be freed later.
dll.my_function.argtypes = ct.c_char_p, ct.POINTER(ct.c_size_t)
dll.my_function.restype = ct.POINTER(ct.c_char)
dll.my_free.argtypes = ct.c_char_p,
dll.my_free.restype = None

def my_function(param):
    # wrap size in a ctypes object so it can be passed by reference
    size = ct.c_size_t(len(param))
    # save the returned pointer
    p = dll.my_function(param, ct.byref(size))
    # slice pointer to convert to an explicitly-sized bytes object
    result = p[:size.value]
    # now the pointer can be freed...
    dll.my_free(p)
    # and the bytes object returned
    return result

result = my_function(b'data\x00more')
print(result)
```

Output:

```
b'data\x00moresome\x00thing'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mark! Your clear and detailed explanation with sample are invaluable. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again