# How to pass a string inside a function in python which is exported from cpp using the library ctypes

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

cpp code snippet where i am exporting the function `encrypt` which takes argument like below

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string Function(char* str) 
{
    
    string temp = str;
    int length = temp.length();
    
    int disp = length,i=0;
    char printChar;
    
    char *store = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    while(disp > 0) {
        printChar = *(str + length - disp);
        if ((printChar >= 65) && (printChar <= 90)) {
            if (printChar+disp > 90) {
                printChar = ((printChar+disp) % 90) + 64;
                store[i] = printChar;
                
            }else{
                printChar += disp;
                store[i] = printChar;
                
            };
        }
        else if ((printChar >= 97) && (printChar <= 122)) {
            if (printChar+disp > 122) {
                printChar = ((printChar+disp) % 122) + 96;
                store[i] = printChar;
                
            }else{
                printChar += disp;
                store[i] = printChar;
                  
            };
        }
        else {
            store[i] = printChar;
            
        };
        disp -= 1;
        i += 1;
    };
    return store;
}
// The part where i am exporting
extern "C" {
    string encrypt(char* str) // this is the functionName(in this case encrypt) which i am giving when exporting
    {
        return Function(str);
    }
}
```

What should be my python code to pass a string in this exported function somewhat like:

```
userString = input()
result = encrypt(userstring) // this is function created in cpp
print(result)
```

I don't know how to use ctypes properly. So please can someone help with this question?

Comment: “C”types can’t do c++ std::string, just types compatible with C, such as char*, so return that. Then you’ll have to deal with freeing the malloc as well

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72479906/235698) for what I just described